# Restricting user to MultiSelect <=5 items only in cardview android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Here is the code for Adapter. Cards change color on selection. I want the user to select <= 5 cards only.  How can I restrict? The user should not be allowed to  select more than 5 cards.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final OptionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final OptionModel option=Options.get(position);
    holder.OptionName.setText(option.getName());
    holder.iv_card.setColorFilter(option.isSelected()? holder.item_view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow) : holder.item_view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Dark_Blue));
   if(!Disabled){
       holder.iv_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                   option.setSelected(!option.isSelected());
                   holder.iv_card.setColorFilter(option.isSelected() ? view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow) : view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Dark_Blue));
           }
       });
   }else {
       holder.iv_card.setOnClickListener(null);
   }

}
```

**Updated code**

```
if (isSelected <= 4 || option.isSelected()) {
                          if (!option.isSelected()) {
                              option.setSelected(!option.isSelected());
                              holder.iv_card.setColorFilter(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
                              isSelected++;
                          } else {
                              option.setSelected(!option.isSelected());
                              holder.iv_card.setColorFilter(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Dark_Blue));
                              isSelected--;
                          }

                      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based your question try to make some changes, like declare an global variable in adapter and then use that variable.

```
    int selectedCards=0;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final OptionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final OptionModel option=Options.get(position);
    holder.OptionName.setText(option.getName());
    holder.iv_card.setColorFilter(option.isSelected()? holder.item_view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow) : holder.item_view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Dark_Blue));
    if(!Disabled){
        holder.iv_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(selectedCards<=5) {
                    selectedCards++;
                    option.setSelected(!option.isSelected());
                    holder.iv_card.setColorFilter(option.isSelected() ? view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow) : view.getResources().getColor(R.color.Dark_Blue));
                }
            }
        });
    }else {
        holder.iv_card.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
```

if you are de-selecting any card then on de-select make sure you are decreasing the global variable's value as

```
selectedCards--;
```

if your query is resolved then mark as correct answer else still there is any question then write here .

Comment: Your code is partially working. I am unable to deselect. I tried the above code u gave

Comment: @ Mr. Mad- where and how do  i write selectedCards-- ?

Comment: Small  correction condition should be <=4

Comment: @AparnaMutnalkar if you need to use deselect card then you need to apply the code in the else condition of selection

Comment: @ Mr. Mad-After 5 cards  are selected if  I select 6th card it should deselect the previous card automatically? Is it possible?

Comment: @Abm Yes possible but the question is if there are 5 cards selected and then select 6th card then  which card from selected 5 cards need to be deselect, 
1st selected card or last selected card ?

Comment: @ Mr. Mad - Last selected card

Comment: @Abm use an global Array/Arraylist to store the selected cards id/name from option object, and then on deselect remove that from the array/arraylist.
also on 6th card selection firslky remove the last position id/name from the array/arraylist and then insert the new one.

Comment: @ Mr. Mad - Can u pls elaborate the code?